# Depending fields in Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, customization, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I would like to know if it's possible and how to do something like this in SharePoint 2010:
I want to add to a document library some custom columns; 2 of them will be of type choice.
I want one of them to be populated after the first has been selected and it will be populated based on the valued chosen by the user in the first drop down list.
Is that possible? How?
Thanks a lot, bye!

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about a master-detail field. There are lots of ways to solve those problem and they all involve creating a custom field.  Here's a write up of my offered approach, with links to various alternatives.

http://www.turimsaint.com/turimBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=2